# Download to PST button not available on eDiscovery Screen

Tags: permissions, exchange-2013, microsoft-office-365, discovery

Environment: Office 365 online. Version 15.1.933.16 (2016 CU4?)

Desktop: IE11, .Net framework 4.5.

So I have setup an eDiscovery on a user in the exchange admin centre following the instructions on https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn440164(v=exchg.160).aspx

The search is completed and I have highlighted the affected row, but I am not presented with the 'Download to PST' button. 
I am a global admin.

Any insight to the next steps in troubleshooting this? I cant seem to find other things to check in my research.

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

We had the same problem. I was a global admin and my colleague was just an 'Exchange Administrator' and 'User Administrator'. My colleague could see the buttons but I couldn't. Changing my role to 'Exchange Administrator' and 'User Administrator' enabled me to see the buttons. I haven't changed it back to 'Global Administrator' yet so I can't say if the buttons are still there once that change is made. Hope that helps.